# Send big file over reactive stream

Tags: spring, stream, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

Part of application I am writing requires transferring arbitrarily big (for this question I will assume 100-200 GB) files from client to server. Important thing, is that receiver (server) is not storing this file - it just read/examine stream and sends it to next point. Because at no point I need whole file, but expect multiple transfers at same time, I would like to minimize RAM usage and eliminate disk usage. I would like to process files in chunks of 1 MB.

Right now, server uses Spring Boot and Akka.

My first attempt was to open buffered file input stream on client side, read it in chunks of 1 MB and send them in messages in separate thread. It works, however problem is that client is sending messages one-after-another without worrying if server has buffer to store it (lacks back pressure).

My second idea was to use akka-streams like this:

[How to use Reactive Streams for NIO binary processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772540/how-to-use-reactive-streams-for-nio-binary-processing)

with use of ActorPublisher like this:

[akka-streams with akka-cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167562/akka-streams-with-akka-cluster#35167791)

however, as stated here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#Implementing_Reactive_Streams_Publisher_or_Subscriber

"Warning
ActorPublisher and ActorSubscriber will probably be deprecated in future versions of Akka.

Warning
ActorPublisher and ActorSubscriber cannot be used with remote actors, because if signals of the Reactive Streams protocol (e.g. request) are lost the the stream may deadlock."

it doesn't look like good idea.

I do not want to save it in any storage provider (dropbox, google drive, ...) because I want to analyze data on-the-fly. I have Spring 5 and Akka on board, but I can use any other software, that will solve this. Raw socket will lack back pressure and torrents do not guarantee sequential/ordered read-write (that I need).

Main question is: how to stream big file from client to server, assuming server is not able to store file at once on disk nor in ram?

Bonus question is: how to calculate "correct" size of chunk in such transfer?

I have been looking for answer for days, and looks like I am not the only one with problem like this, however there are no answers or answers like "don't do it" without pointing out other adequate alternate solution.

Comment: It is not really clear what exactly your problem is. Akka-streams provide all the tools you need - there are stream wrappers around TCP sockets (with backpressure, of course), and there is `GraphStage` (which is the intended replacement for ActorSubscriber and ActorPublisher) which you can use to implement the processing logic if none of the default combinators suit you. You just have to combine them.

Comment: Would You be so kind and show me some minimal example of remote stream, please?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://gist.github.com/netvl/1245564b106c02691dd0808fe98d07eb. It is quite dirty (especially around the server shutdown handling), but it should convey the basic idea. It uses raw TCP sockets for communication; you may also want to use akka-http for that, since it also gives you easier TLS configuration (although probably it can be done with raw TCP streams too). TCP streams are documented [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-tcp), and akka-http is documented [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala.html).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I tried very hard to rewrite Your code into Java, but I am missing something (looks like Akka API isn't exactly same for Java and Scala). Would You case to take a look, please? http://pastebin.com/VKD8GNmd

Comment: Here is my attempt to fix your code: https://gist.github.com/netvl/a8c5024ef9b905a6d6ff32cda8a39872 You mostly got it right. Indeed, Java DSL has minor differences from the Scala API, and it is much more verbose, but the basic idea remains the same. I didn't work with Java API before, so it is possible that something can be optimized there, though.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev much thanks! It indeed works, however I see two problems: I am unable to transmit file name and Server waits Thread.sleep(10000); for all data instead of processing it on-the-fly.

Comment: Of course, this is not a full-fledged implementation, this is just an example of how to do *network I/O* with akka-streams. I said in advance that it is quite dirty. You have to create something based on it specifically for your use case. I'm sorry, but I don't really have a capacity to implement it entirely for you. You have to use the Akka documentation to find out how to do it; I assure you that all the information you need is there, or at least I do not see anything in your question which isn't there.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Yes, You are right, much thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka stream provides functionality specifically for this use case: [streaming File IO](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-io.html#Streaming_File_IO).  From the documentation:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
val file = Paths.get("example.csv")

val foreach: Future[IOResult] = 
  FileIO.fromPath(file)
        .to(Sink.ignore)
        .run()
```

Regarding your bonus question for the "correct size" of chunk; this is highly dependent on your hardware and software configurations.  Your best bet is to write a test client and modulate the chunk size until you find a "sweet spot" for your server.