# Send data from InputStream over Akka/Spring stream

Tags: spring, akka, inputstream, reactive-programming, akka-stream

Here is my previous question: [Send big file over reactive stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328403/send-big-file-over-reactive-stream)

I have managed to send file over Akka stream using FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(file.toURI())) and it works fine. However, I would like to compress and encrypt file before sending it. I have created method, that opens FileInputStream, routes it through compression stream and then through encryption stream and now I would like to direct it into socket using Akka stream.

File -> FileInputStream -> CompressedInputStream -> EncryptedInputStream -?> Spring/Akka stream

The point is, I can compress/encrypt file on-the-fly while reading it chunk by chunk (I am not creating additional files on disk), and I do not see how can I send InputStream (compressed and encrypted) over Akka/Spring stream (by Spring stream I mean Akka stream under project Reactor API).

Question is: how to compress, encrypt and send file without saving whole compressed/encrypted file to disk at no point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have (accidently) found: StreamConverters.fromInputStream!

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/java/stream/stages-overview.html#fromInputStream

Comment: I think that you should accept your own answer instead of mine, since it solves the problem in your question in a much nicer way.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a source specifically for working with resources like input streams. It's called [`Source.unfoldResource`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Source$.html#unfoldResource[T,S](create:akka.japi.function.Creator[S],read:akka.japi.function.Function[S,java.util.Optional[T]],close:akka.japi.function.Procedure[S]):akka.stream.javadsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]):

```
Source<ByteString, NotUsed> source = Source.unfoldResource(
    () -> prepareEncryptedStream(),
    is -> readChunk(is, 4096),
    InputStream::close
);

Optional<ByteString> readChunk(InputStream is, int size) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    int read = is.read(data);
    if (read < 0) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(ByteString.fromArray(data, 0, read));
}

InputStream prepareEncryptedStream() { ... }
```

Here `prepareCompressedFile()` is a method which should return the encrypted stream you want to create a reactive stream from, and `readChunk()` is a convenience method which reads a `ByteString` from an `InputStream` of the specified size.

If you can express compression and encryption routines as `ByteString -> ByteString` functions, then you don't really need this; all you need to do is to pass these routines to the `map()` flow:

```
Source<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> source =
    FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("somewhere"))
        .map(bs -> compress(bs))
        .map(bs -> encrypt(bs));

ByteString encrypt(ByteString bs) { ... }

ByteString compress(ByteString bs) { ... }
```